# Generic Class fails compilation

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method that takes 3 types of elements  , My problem is when ever i try compile it- It fails with error message .

> Duplicate Type Parameter E

I am not able to understand this error as it is perfectly fine to have two elements of different types.

```
public class Test {
    static abstract class Test2<E, E extends MyObject> {
       //At  second E that extends MyObject it is failing.
    }

    class MyObject {
    }

    static <E> void m1(E e,E ee){
    //Same E is working fine in case of Methods 
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Can some one tell me why this compilation fails.

Comment: Both generic parameters have the same name. Which is what "duplicate type parameter" points out. There is no way to differ between the two.

Comment: You have two type parameters both named `E`. Just like with normal method parameters, you cannot have two parameters that have the same name. You have to give them different names. What are you trying to achieve; why do you think that you need to use `E` twice?

Comment: Parameter name is identifier, it's very similar with `foo(int i, int i)`, you cannot have parameter with same name, because you cannot distinguish those two later...

Comment: I don't get why it is that you're thinking `<E, E extends MyObject>` should work. What are you trying to achieve? I think you should [read up on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) and their use. You shouldn't be using generics just because they are generics.

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Both generic parameters have same name `E`.

Use something else, like in coe below and you will be good to go.

```
public class Test {
    static abstract class Test2<E, T extends MyObject> {
       //At E2 it is failing.
    }

    class MyObject {
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I will try to explain using example.

```
class Test2<E, E extends MyObject> //compilation fails here. {
    E generic1;
    E generic2;
}
```

Now, if you are using code like this and declaring two variables `generic1` and `generic2` of same type `E`, there is no way for java to identify if this `E` is first parameter or the second parameter which is subclass of `MyObject`.

Comment: It will work fine for sure... but it will break generics then , I want first element as E and second as subclass of MyObject...:(

Comment: `T extends MyObject` is still subclass of `MyObject`.

Comment: This is work around , Question is why it is getting failing ?

Comment: Because `E` and `E extends MyObject` are the same parameters

Comment: I have edited my code and please check same E is working fine if we use them in Mehods instead of class.

Comment: That `E` is out of scope of the `Test2` class. You are defining a new method and this `E` is not the ones used in `Test2` class generics. Try `X` for example and it will still work fine.

Comment: Furthermore, static methods don't inherit generic the class's generic parameters.

Comment: In `m1()` you are *using* the type parameter twice. Nothing wrong with that. In `Test2` you are *declaring* it twice, even differently; that is not allowed. It is basically the same as for method parameters as @Betlista explained in a comment: you cannot declare `i` twice, but you *can* *use* `i` twice (or many times).

Comment: The answer is not a workaround. It’s a correction of your error.